# Chart.JS + Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I'm newbie in **Angular** and I want to show charts with dynamic data.

I'm trying with **Chart.js** I've made the import and examples works.

So basically the system recieves from PHP JSON data and I show the data.

```
`<div *ngFor="let i of idspreguntas; let f = index">
 <canvas id="{{i}}"></canvas>
 <span *ngIf="f == max2-1" id="inservible">
     {{loadGraphics()}}
 </span>
 </div>`
```

But here is a problem the HTML code executes after I set the Chart properties   and doesn't work.

My solution was check the last position of Array (Previously transformed from JSON) and execute loadGraphics() I gave more time adding timeout per Chart.

```
loadGraphics() {
    $('#inservible').remove();
    let index = 0;
    console.log(this.lista);
    for (const i of this.lista) {
        setTimeout(this.cargaChart(i, index), 2000);
        index++;
    }
}
```

I know this is a very bad practice but I don't know how to make it.

Finally here is the cargaChart function

```
cargaChart(i, u) {
  const respu = [];
  const cont = [];
  if (i.Respuesta1 !== '') {
    respu.push(i.Respuesta1);
    cont.push(i.Contador1);
  }
  if (i.Respuesta2 !== '') {
    respu.push(i.Respuesta2);
    cont.push(i.Contador2);
  }
  if (i.Respuesta3 !== '') {
    respu.push(i.Respuesta3);
    cont.push(i.Contador3);
  }
  if (i.Respuesta4 !== '') {
    respu.push(i.Respuesta4);
    cont.push(i.Contador4);
  }
  if (i.Respuesta5 !== '') {
    respu.push(i.Respuesta5);
    cont.push(i.Contador5);
  }
  if (i.Pregunta !== '') {
    const myChart = new Chart($('#' + i.idPregunta)[0].getContext('2d'), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: respu,
        datasets: [{
          label: i.Pregunta,
          data: cont,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            }
          }]
        }
      },
    });
  }
}
```

This is de unique method that is worked for me. (Almost)

> The last dataof array doesn't work console said 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined'

But only in the last position, others positions works well.

Here the JSON

```
[{"idPregunta":"04QLDT5S","NumeroPregunta":"3","Nombre":"¿Quién eres?","Pregunta":"¿Quién eres?","Respuesta1":"Yo","Contador1":"0","Respuesta2":"Tú","Contador2":"1","Respuesta3":"Ella","Contador3":"0","Respuesta4":"","Contador4":0,"Respuesta5":"","Contador5":0},{"idPregunta":"0Z000BZ8","Pregunta":"Qué hace","Respuesta1":"Nada","Contador1":"0","Respuesta2":"Llorando","Contador2":"0","Respuesta3":"Triste","Contador3":"0","Respuesta4":"","Contador4":"0","Respuesta5":"","Contador5":"0"},{"idPregunta":"0Y2FG4XL","Pregunta":"¿Qué duces=","Respuesta1":"Nada","Contador1":"0","Respuesta2":"Algo","Contador2":"0","Respuesta3":"Simbólico","Contador3":"0","Respuesta4":"Majestuoso","Contador4":"0","Respuesta5":"Brilante","Contador5":"0"}]
```

Sorry for all.. I'm learning.

Comment: Did you debug your code and set a breakpoint on the getContext line?

Comment: I see the DebugContext and data, ids, preguntas are okay. If u want I uploaded in my sitie the project.

Comment: better use `ViewChild` rather than getting the canvas element via `id`

Comment: viewChild can be dynamic ? add innumerable questions?

Comment: What version of angular? I use chart.js with Angular 5 and just set the data to a variable that i set in ngAfterViewInit - this.chartData = [
                  {
                    data: tempChartData
                    ,
                    backgroundColor...

Comment: I use Angular: 5.2.11